# Master View's Back Navigation in Split View Not Working with Display Modes "Auto" or "primaryHidden"

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

For my app, I have created a split view embedded in a container view, i.e. the split view is not at the root of the application.

As can be seen in the image, I added a navigation item to the master view that serves as a back button and pops the entire split view off the main navigation stack.

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    parent?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This is working well on all devices when I set the split view's display mode to `allVisible`. It works both for the collapsed view (e.g. on iPhone portrait mode) and the expanded split view.

[image]

**Problem:** When I use another display mode such as `Auto` or `primaryHidden` the navigation button in the master view still shows but does not work in landscape (expanded) view. The button handler is called but above statement does not navigate away from the split view. The parent's navigation controller does not seem to be accessible this way (= nil). Why doesn't the statement work in some display modes, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels a bit clumsy, but it does the job. A better solution may come from understanding why the parent navigation controller is accessible in some display mode but not in others.

What does work is going via the detail view's navigation controller and removing that from the stack. The display mode is changed here to prevent some ugly transition effect.

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if (splitViewController!.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        // master and detail visible in split view
        let detailViewController = splitViewController!.viewControllers[1]
        splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
        detailViewController.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    } else {
        // split view collapsed into single view mode (e.g. iPhone portrait)
        parent?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```